# Spring Bean throws NullPointerException other than execute and validate method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2, dependency-injection

I am integrated Spring with Struts2. I use bean for creating session from session factory. My code is below. If I use bean in execute or validate my method works, other place it throws `NullPointerException`.

**Action Class:**

```
public class GetEmp extends ActionSupport {
  private spDao myDao;
  public String execute(){
    User user=myDao.getDbsession().get(User.class);
  }
}
```

It works fine. If I use the same bean in other class that not extend `ActionSupport` throws `NullPointerException`.

**`applicationContext.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="myDao" class="controller.spDAO" scope="request" /> 
    <bean id="sendMail" class="controller.Emailfunction" scope="request"/>

</beans>
```

**Java class:**

```
public class GetEmp {
  private spDao myDao;
  public String getEmpname(){
    User user=myDao.getDbsession().get(User.class);
  }
}
```

throws `NullPointerException`. How to resolve this problem?

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Matrimonial</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/503.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

I managed this problem by passing my bean name with method. Is their any other solution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Where does the null pointer exception came from?

Comment: @gerrytan,when calling myDao.getDbsession().

Comment: can you show your config file,where you have defined your bean and injected dependencies in the action class

Comment: @umaesh  Awasthi,i addeed  configuration file in my question.

Comment: where are the configurations for the actions items? you must be injecting your `DAO` in your action class in some way

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi,i did this in applicationContext.xml  <bean id="myDao" class="controller.spDAO" scope="request" /> .

Comment: That is only way to create a bean in the spring, but in your action class you have to inject this bean? how you are creating your action classes? are you using struts2-spring plugin to create and manage struuts2 component using spring?

Comment: private spDao myDao; inject bean to action class.i am using struts2-spring plugin.i specified my action class in my question.

Comment: Why do you expect this code will not throw NullPointerException??, Have you anywhere injected myDao in GetEmp class?

Comment: @Himanshu I inject bean ->private spDao myDao;

Comment: Read about how DI works. Container has to manage both beans in order to inject one into another.

Comment: @Madhesh: This is not injection, have you anywhere defined via xml or annotation that this bean should be injected or have you defined any autowiring policy. As Aleksandr mentioned, first study about spring.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Struts2 autowiring action classes and by default the policy is by name. OP has resolved the problem using this policy but asked for other solution.

Comment: @RomanC,you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is if you are using spring-plugin to create an action bean by Spring, and configure dependency to be injected

```
<bean id="getEmp" class="controller.GetEmp" scope="request"> 
    <property name="myDao" ref="myDao" />     
</bean>
```

In the `struts.xml` you should have something

```
<action name="getEmp" class="getEmp" method="getEmpname"/>
```

Read more about [Struts2-Spring](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html) usage and explanation.